# Log datalist value when pressing with mouse

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running into a problem. How can I console.log the selected option/value from the datalist when selecting/clicking with my mouse?

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var options = Array.from(document.querySelector("datalist").options).map(function(el){
  return el.innerHTML;
}); //Optional if you have data
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    var relevantOptions = options.filter(function(option){
      return option.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase());
    }); // filtering the data list based on input query
    if(relevantOptions.length > 0){
      input.value = relevantOptions.shift(); //Taking the first
      console.log(input.value)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input list='typesOfFruit' placeholder="Enter a fruit...">

<datalist id='typesOfFruit'>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, select your element and add an eventListener to it that listens to 'change'

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', (e) => { console.log(e.target.value) })
```

In your example just do this

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
// above mentioned eventListener
    input.addEventListener('change', function(event){
      console.log(`selected value: ${event.target.value}`)
    })

    var options = Array.from(document.querySelector("datalist").options).map(function (el) {
        return el.innerHTML;
    }); //Optional if you have data
    input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var relevantOptions = options.filter(function (option) {
                return option.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase());
            }); // filtering the data list based on input query
            if (relevantOptions.length > 0) {
                input.value = relevantOptions.shift(); //Taking the first
                console.log(input.value)
            }
        }
});
```